# Create a new model from another model data

Tags: laravel

I have the following structure (this is actually a Model but I'm using JSON here to make it easier to represent what I'm looking after):

```json
{
  "id": 1,
  "event": {
    "id": 2,
    "source": "browser-sdk"
  }
}
```

What I would like is to transform this model into pulling `event` to be top object:

```json
{
  "id": 2,
  "source": "browser-sdk",
  "eventable": {
    "id": 1,
  }
}
```

What I have tried so far is:

```php
$event = new Event([
  'id' => $existingModel->event->id,
  'source' => $existingModel->event->source,
])

$event->setRelation('eventable', $existingModel);

dd($event);
```

`$event` is missing the `id`. How can I create a model in-memory based on data from another model?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `Event` has `id`, and other fields as restricted. The way to solve this is to assign `id` outside of the mass assinable values:

```php
$event = new Event([
  'source' => $existingModel->event->source,
]);

$event->id = $existingModel->event->id;

$event->setRelation('eventable', $existingModel);
```